# Unable to connect to internet on Vmware workstation 12

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, vmware-workstation

I'm having some trouble attempting to access the internet on my Ubuntu VM, with a Windows 7 host.

I've done my research and have bridged the network adapters
[image]

I've also gone onto my host and checked the connections, they are bridged. I've also gone into my virtual network editor and checked there
[image]

Why am I unable to bridge my network onto my VM, is there something simple that I'm missing? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

`ifconfig` command from the guest terminal:
[image]

Interface file:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I attempted run `dhclient` here's what I got:

```
:~$ sudo dhclient -v -4 -d
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/ens33/00:0c:29:71:6f:a8
Sending on   LPF/ens33/00:0c:29:71:6f:a8
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on ens33 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x12c4110b)
DHCPDISCOVER on ens33 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x12c4110b)
DHCPDISCOVER on ens33 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x12c4110b)
DHCPDISCOVER on ens33 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x12c4110b)
DHCPDISCOVER on ens33 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x12c4110b)
DHCPDISCOVER on ens33 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x12c4110b)
DHCPDISCOVER on ens33 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x12c4110b)
```

Comment: I assume you have configured your Ubuntu VM with appropriate IP address details? Can you post a screenshot of your network config on the guest?

Comment: work or home environment? In a previous company I worked the bridged was not working as the network security policy would only lease IP addresses to the connected physical NIC. at home you (I assume) have a device (ADSL modem) which hands out the IP addresses? as @MarkoPolo suggested, please edit your question with a ifconfig screenshot.

Comment: @MarkoPolo Added the image

Comment: @Zina Its at work

Comment: as you see you do not have an IP on the ens33 interface - which probably is caused by a network policy. Why not use a NAT network for your VMs which will gain access to Internet through your host's NIC?

Comment: @Zina I'm not sure that NAT will work, I just tried it and my VM is telling me I'm off the network

Comment: What is the actual interface configuration for ens33? Check `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: could you share the NAT network settings as you shared the host-only one?

Comment: and that what @MarkoPolo said :)

Comment: I'm attempting to reinstall VMware, after it installs I'll add the information

Comment: @MarkoPolo Added the interface file to the question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Bridge option, use NAT (Network Address Translator). If your host OS is connected to the internet, you can just auto-configure your virtual Ethernet adapter using the following command and you'll be online:

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

The above command automatically gets you an IP address using DHCP protocol and you are all set.

Comment: `~$ sudo dhclient eth0
Cannot find device "eth0"
~$ `

Comment: You do not have an eth0 interface. Change the command to `sudo dhclient ens33`. The reason why you cannot connect to the internet is because the network interface on your VM (ens33) does not have an IP address. You will either need to configure one statically or use DHCP.

Comment: @13aal, I read above that you are reinstalling the VM. After that, do not modify any of the network configuration, just issue this command and let us know where you get.

Comment: Replacing eth0 with ens33 of course. eth0 is the name Virtual Box gives you.

Comment: It froze my vm.

Comment: The command works out of the box on VirtualBox which uses NAT by default. I'm surprised. Mind issuing `ifconfig` to check if ens33 is still the name of your Virtual Ethernet card? Or, if internet connection is not a problem, download Virtual Box and install Ubuntu there.